# Is there a single regression quality metric for the median and the 95% percentile?

Tags: model-evaluation, quantiles, prediction-interval, mae

I want to evaluate the quality of prediction of two values the median and 95% percentile of a distribution. Is there a standard way to do this? I have thought about using "Mean Mean Average Error" of the two targets. With this I mean

$$\text{MMAE} = \frac{\text{MAE of the median} + \text{MAE of the 95% percentile}}{2}$$

So if predicted median is 17 and the true median is 15, MAE would be 2. If the predicted 95% percentile is 20 and the true median is 19, MAE would be 1. MMAE for this example would be 1.5. I want to penalize distance to the target evenly, and not quadratically, which is why I'm not using mean MSE.

Is this a common practice? I haven't found much literature about it. [This example in the ML Mastery blog uses MAE](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prediction-intervals-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/), but it's not really what I want, as it's compared against a single prediction target and the target 95% is a true value for my application.

For this application, I only care about these two particular values: median and 95% percentile not the shape of the distribution between them.

Comment: This does not seem like a standard problem, so it may not have a standard answer. The one you came up with may be fine depending on your loss function (how painful different kinds of mistakes are for you or your client). Other than that, consider using [proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info). Separate ones for the median and a $q$-level quantile should be available in the literature. One for a joint prediction is probably not available, but perhaps it could be derived.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the true median"? How did you "observe" this? The more typical proper scoring setup involves crafting a consistent scoring function for the $\alpha$-quantile (e.g. quantile score) where you compare your predicted quantile to the actual observation, not to some "true" quantile. In that case, Gneiting & Raftery (2007) show a version of the quantile score that is proper for multiple levels jointly.

Comment: @ChrisHaug I have historical data for these distributions. I can observe the true median and the true 95 percentile in January, February, etc. Thanks for the reference to the paper, I will study it. Here is a link for those interested https://sites.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/Gneiting2007jasa.pdf